# Why delete and recreate a querydef object when you can just change the .SQL property?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Do you remember the venerable old Microsoft Query by Form (QBF) VBA example from back in the day [**link**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117544/en-us) that recommended that you delete an existing query and then recreate it dynamically?:

```
On Error Resume Next
db.QueryDefs.Delete ("qryResults")
On Error GoTo 0

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("qryResults", "SELECT p.*...
```

Why not just change the SQL property of the querydef object?

```
qdf.SQL = "SELECT p.*...
```

I am wondering if anyone knows why the MS engineers wrote an example that suggests that you delete and then recreate a query instead of simply changing the SQL property? I would guess that the act of deleting and recreating objects over time could contribute to corruption and bloating in your front end, not to mention changing the SQL property is so much simpler. Does anyone have more insight into this?

Comment: Can you supply the MS Engineers reference, please? The example may have been simply to avoid the problem of checking if the query existed before creating or modifying.

Comment: I imagine they are deleting it for "clean-up" sake. I saw on one the examples the note was `"Delete QueryDef because this is just an example."` Creating a permanent QueryDef also saves it to disk. That could also have something to do with why they deleted it. And for you to say it is simpler - that's ambiguous because you wouldn't have a querydef named `AllEmployeesQry` and then change the `SQL` property to return employees that have died, or who have a birthday this year. Think of encapsulation.

Comment: Fionnuala - I added the link.

Comment: Overmind - This is for a dynamic query that returns results based upon a user's selections on a form. There is a permanent querydef saved to disk as the record source of the results. The question is why do they recommend deleting the old querydef and creating a new querydef instead of simply changing the where clause of the SQL property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never question the wisdom of Microsoft. Microsoft never makes mistakes. :-)

OK, real answer. I strongly suspect it's because the article was first written for Microsoft Access 2.0 Standard Edition. I used to work with with Access 2.0, and there was a LOT that couldn't be done back in the day.

As for best practice, I would say change the SQL property. Deleting and recreating an object will cause your DB to bloat because the old object isn't really deleted, just marked as such until you do a compact. Changing the SQL property doesn't create a new object, just changes it.

Comment: +1 Access 2.0 was certainly very different. Of course you still need to check that the query exists to choose whether to create or alter the SQL.

Comment: OK +1 for proper programming. But if an object is an integral part of my DB, I don't check to see if it was accidentally deleted before accessing it. I'm going to assume that all the objects I created are still there.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that is what I assumed but I just wanted to hear other's opinions.

Comment: Question - I would like to know if the following is considered as a good pratice or not. If the querydef is alter by code (code in form or module) during the apps running, does creation of querydef and deletion of should be processed at the opening and closing the apps respectively.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're altering a querydef, there shouldn't be any creations or deletions.

Comment: Ok let explain differently by an example. Someone give you a database  from another developer.  In the database there is 100 queries in the database windows. 50 % of these query are altered by code. When you look a the code more deeply, you realize that  all of the 50 % altered query are created via code but never deleted at the end of the apps. my is question is. Is it good practice to show only the non altered queries in the database windows to avoid confusion between non altered queries and and altered queries.

Comment: Personally, I would just use a different naming convention on the dynamic queries. There's no standard that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal.